# React native flexbox position view below

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, react-native-paper

Result I want to get:

[image]

Result I got:

[image]

I have to make sure to position the view with a transparent background, with the writing and the badge inside, at the bottom as seen in the image above.

If I use the `marginTop` inside the `Card.Content` it works, but the problem that the text is variable, I tried to use `alignContent: 'flex-end'` but it doesn't work.

Can you give me a hand?

Link expo: [link](https://snack.expo.dev/7sJypIlMJl)

Code:

```js
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import { Card, Chip } from 'react-native-paper';
import { FlatGrid } from 'react-native-super-grid';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatGrid
        itemDimension={160}
        data={[0, 1]}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Card style={{ height: 160 }}>
            <ImageBackground
              source={{
                uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/React-icon.svg/1200px-React-icon.svg.png',
              }}
              style={{
                height: 160,
                borderRadius: 4,
                overflow: 'hidden',
              }}>
              <Card.Content
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
                  //marginTop: 100,
                  //backgroundColor: '#ccc000'
                  //alignContent: 'flex-end',
                }}>
                <View
                  style={{
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    justifyContent: 'space-between',
                    backgroundColor: '#987ccc',
                    alignContent: 'flex-end',
                  }}>
                  <View style={{ width: 120, backgroundColor: '#000ccc' }}>
                    <Text variant="bodySmall" style={{ color: '#fff' }}>
                      React native React native React native React native
                    </Text>
                    <Text variant="bodySmall" style={{ color: '#fff' }}>
                      2 hours ago
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <Chip
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: '#1faeb3',
                      height: 28,
                    }}>
                    Ep 400
                  </Chip>
                </View>
              </Card.Content>
            </ImageBackground>
          </Card>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 30,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your code. commented out the Card.component and added some styles properties in your existing code. You can try with this code below:

```js
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ImageBackground } from "react-native";
import { Card, Chip } from "react-native-paper";
import { FlatGrid } from "react-native-super-grid";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatGrid
        itemDimension={160}
        data={[0, 1]}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Card style={{ height: 160 }}>
            <ImageBackground
              source={{
                uri: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/React-icon.svg/1200px-React-icon.svg.png",
              }}
              style={{
                height: 160,
                borderRadius: 4,
                overflow: "hidden",
              }}
            >
              {/* <Card.Content
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
                  //marginTop: 100,
                  //backgroundColor: '#ccc000'
                  //alignContent: 'flex-end',
                }}
              > */}
                <View
                  style={{
                    position: "absolute",
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    justifyContent: "space-between",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    padding: 8
                  }}
                >
                  <View style={{ width: "60%" }}>
                    <Text variant="bodySmall" style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
                      React native React native React native React native
                    </Text>
                    <Text variant="bodySmall" style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
                      2 hours ago
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <Chip
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: "#1faeb3",
                      height: 28,
                    }}
                  >
                    Ep 400
                  </Chip>
                </View>
              {/* </Card.Content> */}
            </ImageBackground>
          </Card>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: 30,
    backgroundColor: "#000",
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```